# Unable to run selenium web driver project for 3.8.1 version

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Unable to run web `driver 3.8.1` `geckodriver 0.19.1` with guava 21 and 22 . 
Firefox version 58.0.2 (64-bit)
getting error as :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

running on iMac

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//Users//(username)//Downloads//engage-test//engage-test-common//exes//geckodriver");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
driver= new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

### Class **`NoSuchMethodError`**

**`public class NoSuchMethodError`** extends **`IncompatibleClassChangeError`** and as per the **`Java Docs`** it is thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler and this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

### Solution

Perform the following steps :

- When providing *absolute paths* either use double back slashes `(\\)` or single front slashes `(/)`. Both are equivalent. So you need to update the `System.setProperty()` as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/<username>/Downloads/engage-test/engage-test-common/exes/geckodriver"); //Linux Style
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  ```
- Update your JDK to the most recent versions [*JDK 8u161*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Upgrade *Selenium-Java Clients* to [**v3.10.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Clean up the *Project Space* from your IDE.
- Run [***CCleaner***](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS system chores.
- If your base *Web Browser* version is too old, then uninstall it through [***Revo Uninstaller***](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of the *Web Browser*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your *@Test*

---

### Update

As you are using **Selenium-Java Client 3.11.0** where support of **DesiredCapabilities** is deprecated from the list of constructors for [FirefoxDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) Class you have to use the method [merge(Capabilities extraCapabilities)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) and merge the capabilities into an [FirefoxOptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) Class object  as follows :

```
package demo;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class A_Firefox_DC_Opt 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability("marionatte", true);
        FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
        opt.merge(dc);
        FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        System.out.println("Application opened");
        System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Console Output :

```
1522037759633   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.0
1522037759653   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:20073
1522037760415   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ATECHM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.hRnaFvWiVBua"
1522037762202   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
1522037765376   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 1176
1522037765636   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Mar 26, 2018 9:46:05 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Application opened
Page Title is : Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
```

Comment: I tried with Selenium-Java Client 3.11.0, Guava 23, geckodriver 20 for firefox and getting error
Note: Firefox  path is not default. Any idea how to execute from specified path as they depricated  constructor FirefoxDriver(Capabilities)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonParseException
 at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.constructMessage(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:37)
 at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.<init>(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:29)

Comment: @user2805845 Check my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: I tried the same script but nothing works. (Updated geckodriver path)
Below are the versions java Client 3.11.0, geckdriver 20 and Guava 23 using firefox version 59.0.1 



1522120514507 geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.20.0
1522120514517 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:41633
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonParseException
 at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.constructMessage(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:37)
 at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.<init>(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:29)